# Make div element stretch full height of page

Tags: css, angularjs

I have built this little ap in angular and would like to the container element to stretch the full height of the page, when the content doesn't fill the height of the page for example on a large screen this page doesn't:

http://purepremier.com/#/teams/57

I tried setting it to

```
position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0; 
height:100%
```

but when the content overflows then the height of the container only stretchs to the viewport height.

Any ideas? Or is theere a way in angular to add the class to the body instead?

Comment: You can use height: 100vh; (vh means viewport height). So 100vh basically means "the screen's height"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uf2u32gf/ i saw this online, i am not sure how vh work in all browser.

Comment: just look it up http://caniuse.com/#search=vh not sure if you are ok with it.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking exactly. So voting to close.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, simply

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Luwtnrer/3/)

[**Support for viewport units**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

---

Or for an alternative

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: browser support of "vh" it's ie9+. who uses ie8 nowadays?

Comment: I just realized that viewport unit is not the way. It just get the vieport height not document height.

Comment: But OP wants to set document height not just viewport height.

Comment: may we are wrong but seeing `...only stretchs to the viewport height` I thought.

Comment: My linked [**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Luwtnrer/) seem to indicate (in Chrome) that the container continues to cover for any height of content even if there isn't enough. Try running the fiddle with and without the height of the "expander" div.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning is not the way to set full document height, but it sets to the viewport height. You can use fixed position instead:

```
#element{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
html, body {height:100%; min-height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
#full {background:red; height:100%;}
```

```html
<div id='full'>hmm</div>
```